# rescue_from NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having problems figuring this out.

trying to do a

```
rescue_from NoMethodError, :with => :try_some_options
```

But its not working.

EDITED:
For testing I'm doing a simple redirect

```
def try_some_options
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

EDITED 2:
Sample of my controller.  Added (exception) as recommended below.

I know the reason I'm getting the error. Using Authlogic and authlogic_facebook_connect plugin.  When user is created from the facebook plugin the "MyCar" model, which is associated with a user is not created like it normally is created if a user registers locally.  Since I do call on the user model and reference the users car throughout different parts of the site, I would like to do something like what you see below and eventually put it in my application_controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :login_required, :except => [:new, :create]
 rescue_from NoMethodError, :with => :try_some_options

 ...

 def show
    store_target_location
    @user = current_user
  end

 def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    MyCar.create!(:user => @user)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created profile."
    redirect_to profile_path
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
 end
 ...

 protected

 def try_some_options(exception)
    if logged_in? && current_user.my_car.blank?
       MyCar.create!(:user => current_user)
       redirect_to_target_or_default profile_path
    end
 end
 ...
end
```

EDITED 3: Hacked it for now since I know why the error is showing up, but would like to figure out how to rescue_from NoMethodError

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :login_required, :except => [:new, :create]
 before_filter :add_car_if_missing

 def add_car_if_missing
   if logged_in? && current_user.my_car.blank?
     MyCar.create!(:user => current_user)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: It's not firing the "try_some_options" method.

Comment: What does the code look like where you trigger this exception?

Comment: Are you sure the NoMethodError gets thrown in the UsersController? Maybe you are redirecting to another controller where the NoMethodError doesn't get rescued yet.

Comment: I know that I call the user and the user.my_car in different partials, but only referenced once in "Show".  That's where I'm concentrating for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just read your post when trying to come up with a solution to the same problem. In the end I did the following:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_404
  ...

private

  def render_404(exception = nil)
    logger.info "Exception, redirecting: #{exception.message}" if exception
    render(:action => :index)
  end
end
```

This worked well for me. It is a catch all situation yet it just may help you. All the best.

Comment: This! Is the best answer hands down...even 9 years later!