# Render page doesn’t exist Like Twitter in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, rendering, http-status-code-404

How do I render a 404 or page doesn't exist like Twitter does?
I use rails 3.2.3

My code

```
def rescue_with_handler(exception)
  redirect_to '/500.html'
end

def method_missing(id, *args)
 redirect_to '/404.html'
end
```

That works, but I want to be like twitter. For example if I access this page
https://twitter.com/abcd/skka/asafaga
and https://twitter.com/abcd/skka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle `Routing Error` with `rescue_from`.

This question was already answered:

- [Dynamic error pages in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331008/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails-3)
- [Best way to handle 404 in Rails3 controllers with a DataMapper get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515263/best-way-to-handle-404-in-rails3-controllers-with-a-datamapper-get)
- [rescue_from NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632224/rescue-from-nomethoderror)
- ...

Also there is solution here:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671

In any case, try to Google it, you will find a lot of different solutions.